# How to pivot all rows value using sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

```
ID      grp  find
534-1   A    OK
534-1   A    Good
534-1   B    Good
534-1   C    OK
534-2   A    AVERAGE
```

I wanted to display above table using pivot, It should display all value from above table like this

```
ID       A          B         C    
534-1    OK        Good       OK    
534-1    Good      NULL       NULL 
534-2    Average   NULL       NULL
```

I'm using following query

```
select * 
     from
     #temp1
     pivot(MAX(find)
      for grp in ([A]
     ,[B]
     ,[C])) pvt
```

But, I'm getting following output, which is missing another value for `534-1`.

```
ID       A         B         C
534-1    OK        Good      OK
534-2    Average   NULL      NULL
```

Anyone have any idea what am I missing here ?

Comment: You're displaying the `max` of `OK` and `Good`.  That should be `OK` instead of `Good`... edited in question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try:

```
select ID,[A],[B],[C] 
from(
    select *,row_number() over (partition by grp order by grp) Col from #temp1
)x pivot
     (MAX(find)
      for grp in ([A]
      ,[B]
      ,[C])) as y
```

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1a327/1/0)

Comment: +1 This approach works by adding a column `Col`.  The pivot now works on `ID, Col`, which is allows multiple rows if there are multiple `grp` for a single `ID`.

Comment: Thanks. Its working as I wanted, but I see one problem here. I'm getting one row for each ID as `NULL`